# What is a super-infinity-groupoid, homotopy-theoretically?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, supermanifolds

There's a sheafy way to write down the $\infty$-category of super-$\infty$-groupoids, as detailed [on the nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/super+infinity-groupoid). Can this notion be reformulated by saying that a super-$\infty$-groupoid is an ordinary $\infty$-groupoid plus some homotopy-theoretic data?

The sheafy notion is this: let $sMan$ be the usual category of supermanifolds, regarded as a site with the usual Grothendieck topology (a cover is a jointly surjective collection of open embeddings). Consider the $\infty$-category $Sh(sMan)$ of sheaves of $\infty$-groupoids on this site, and then localize at the morphisms $\mathbb R^{p|q} \to \mathbb R^{0|q}$. If we did this same process with the site $Man$ of ordinary manifolds, we'd end up with the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-groupoids, so when we do it here, the resulting $\infty$-category deserves to be called the $\infty$-category $sGpd_\infty$ of super-$\infty$-groupoids. There is a natural forgetful functor $|-|: sGpd_\infty \to Gpd_\infty$ induced by the forgetful functor $sMan \to Man$.

**Question:** What additional homotopy-theoretic data is needed to recover a super-$\infty$-groupoid $X$ from its underlying $\infty$-groupoid $|X|$? Can this be formulated cleanly enough to give an alternative construction of the $\infty$-category $sGpd_\infty$?

The kind of data I have in mind is that maybe $X$ can be recovered from the data of $|X|$ plus maybe a map from $|X|$ into the classifying space of some sort of structure group, or something of that sort.

Comment: I wonder if the standard argument tells you you're getting the sifted cocompletion of the subcategory on disjoint unions of $R^{0|q}$'s? So it's like we need a more concrete description of the 'category of supersets' where the usage of the word 'supersets' is... unfortunate.

Comment: According to the nLab page super-$\infty$-groupoids are indeed presheaves on the category of $\mathbb R^{0|q}$'s, and $|-|$ is evaluation at $\mathbb R^{0|0}$ (which is a zero object). Since this category is not a groupoid there isn't a simple "classifying space" description. It seems the maximal subgroupoid is the groupoid of real vector spaces, so a super-$\infty$-groupoid has an underlying collection of $\infty$-groupoids $X_n$ with the discrete group $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ acting on $X_n$...

Comment: @MarcHoyois Wow, that is indeed what it says -- I should get better at reading! Now I'm no longer sure whether the definition I've written down is equivalent to what's on the nlab. In fact, I'm pretty sure it's not -- I think I believe that in the definition I gave, everything is determined by a presheaf on the category of $\mathbb R^{0|q}$'s, but I think that under my definition, there are further identifications because there are non-equal maps between $\mathbb R^{0|q}$'s which are $\mathbb R^{1|0}$-homotopic.

Comment: Hmm, indeed. Actually, aren't all $\mathbb R^{0|q}$'s homotopy equivalent, so you'd just get $\infty$-groupoids back?

Comment: Actually in your description you only localize wrt $\mathbb R^{p|q}\to \mathbb R^{0|q}$, not all $\mathbb R^{1|0}$-homotopies, so I think it's equivalent to the nLab.

Comment: ok but maybe the category of 'superpoints' isn't so bad. Is this just the opposite of the category of finite-dimensional exterior algebras over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @DylanWilson Yes, with $\mathbb Z/2$-grading.

Comment: But $\mathbb R^{p|q} = \mathbb R^{p|0} \times \mathbb R^{0|q}$, no? So by localizing at these maps, are at least respecting $\mathbb R^{1|0}$ homotopies between maps between $\mathbb R^{0|q}$'s.

Comment: @TimCampion I don't think there are any interesting homotopies between maps between 'superpoints'

Comment: @TimCampion You're right! Dylan: It seems to me any two maps are homotopic, but perhaps I am not using the definitions correctly.

Comment: @DylanWilson For instance, a map $\mathbb R^{1|1} \to \mathbb R^{0|1}$ corresponds to a map $\mathbb R[\epsilon] / \epsilon^2 \to C(\mathbb R)[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$, which is specified by where $\epsilon$ goes, namely to some $h\epsilon$, where $h \in C(\mathbb R)$. This serves as a homotopy between the maps $\mathbb R^{0|1} \rightrightarrows \mathbb R^{0|1}$ given by $h(0) \epsilon$ and $h(1)\epsilon$.

Comment: If any two maps are made homotopic, then since there are maps in both directions everywhere, all maps are inverted, so any sheaf descends to the classifying space. Since the category of superpoints has a terminal object, the classifying space is contractible. So with the definition I've given, a super-$\infty$-groupoid is just an $\infty$-groupoid. I'm not sure what to make of the nlab's definition.

Comment: The definition I gave was motivated by wanting to somehow incorporate the topology on $\mathbb R$ in a way that the nlab's definition doesn't. There's a clear option to do this -- go condensed!